# GOlang: отправка POST xml запроса

Tags: xml, post, golang

Здравствуйте!
Вопрос, наверное, глупый и, возможно, тривиальный, но я никак не могу разобраться и прошу вашей помощи.
Пытаюсь получить доступ к API https://russia.travel/apidoc/access/ с помощью Go. 
Цитата:

> Russia.Travel API работает по HTTP протоколу, по которому все запросы
>   необходимо отправлять методом POST на адрес http://api.russia.travel/.
>   В передаваемых запросах должно содержаться три обязательных параметра:
>
> login, содержащий логин пользователя; hash, содержащий хеш пароля
>   пользователя; xml, содержащий тело запроса в формате XML в
>   соответствии с документацией

Вот, что я делаю:

```
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://api.russia.travel/", strings.NewReader(xmlbody))
    req.SetBasicAuth("view", "view")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error! %s", err)
    }
```

И получаю ошибку 400: неверный синтаксис запроса. В xml-теле запроса я уверена, отправка его в песочницу дает нужный результат. В связи с чем думаю, что дело в логине-хэше, скорее всего, я не там (не так) их использую?

Буду очень благодарна за помощь или хотя бы намек, в какую сторону двигаться.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решен: https://play.golang.org/p/_mCBF8LSTR

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

    xmlBody := `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request action="get-library" type="object-type" />`

    form := url.Values{}
    form.Add("login", "view")
    form.Add("hash", "view")
    form.Add("xml", xmlBody)

    resp, _ := http.PostForm("http://api.russia.travel", form)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    fmt.Println(string(body[:len(body)]))

}
```

Спасибо Никите Грицай из группы вк по Go.